# Sum Distinct By Other Column

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a problem with PL/SQL since i am new in PL/SQL world.
Let's say i have table like this.

```
COlumnA  COlumnB    COlumnC
1      5000000000   X
1      5000000000   X
2      4350000000   X
2      4350000000   X
3      10000000000  X
3      10000000000  X
3      10000000000  X
4      1809469720   Y
5      10000000000  X
5      10000000000  X
6      3000000000   X
6      3000000000   X
```

And i want to produce select statement as below.

```
ColumnC |Sum
X       |32350000000
Y       |1809469720
```

I have solved this problem in Oracle 12c with inner query, but when the system need to go to Oracle 11g, my query doesn't work anymore, i need to have the expected result with only one select statement.

Could anyone please advise?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show your query `Oracle 12c` query. Moreover this is a very basic SQL question doesnot require any special function to solve this so please show your original query

Comment: Hi Prdp, 
Below is my query in Oracle 12c, but it'doesnt work in 11g because oracle11g doens't support more than 1 level of subquery, CMIIW.
select a.ColumnC,(SELECT SUM(ColumnB)FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA,ColumnB FROM tableA where ColumnC = a.ColumnC)) 
 from tableA a group by ColumnC;

Comment: What happens when you do this `select ColumnC,sum(ColumnB)
from Table1
group by ColumnC`

Comment: I am sorry but i have to updated the data because the first data that i provided is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with... using an inline view rather than a correlated subquery in the SELECT list.

```
  SELECT d.columnc        AS "ColumnC"
       , SUM(d.columnb)   AS "Sum"
    FROM ( SELECT t.columna
                , t.columnb
                , t.columnc
             FROM tablea t
            GROUP
               BY t.columna
                , t.columnb
                , t.columnc
         ) d
   GROUP
      BY d.columnc
```

This uses an inline view (aliased as "d") to return a "distinct" set of rows from tablea.  We can get a distinct set, using a GROUP BY clause, or including the DISTINCT keyword, or even by writing a query that uses a UNION set operator.

Just wrap that query in parens, assign an alias, and use it in the FROM clause, as if it were a table or view.

The statement operates similarly to referencing a VIEW in the FROM clause.

You don't need to do this, but to illustrate how the query above operates. We could create a view, like this:

```
  CREATE VIEW d AS 
           SELECT t.columna
                , t.columnb
                , t.columnc
             FROM tablea t
            GROUP
               BY t.columna
                , t.columnb
                , t.columnc
```

And then we can reference the view in the FROM clause of another query, for example

```
  SELECT d.columnc        AS "ColumnC"
       , SUM(d.columnb)   AS "Sum"
    FROM d
   GROUP
      BY d.columnc
```

But we don't actually need to create the VIEW object. We can include the view query as an "inline view".

---

I don't believe that Oracle 11g has a restriction on the nesting of inline views to three levels. I suspect that the restriction you are running into is related to correlated subqueries. The subquery can reference columns from the outer query, but only up one level... columns from the query it's used in. It can't reference columns in a query that is further out. (I've not confirmed with testing, but that's my recollection.)

This is where the actual ORA- and/or PLS- error message from Oracle would be of some help in identifying the restriction you are running into.

Answer (score 0):

First find the `distinct` values of `COlumnA`,`COlumnB` and `COlumnC` then do the aggregation

Try this

```
select COlumnC,sum(COlumnB) from
(
select distinct COlumnA,COlumnB,COlumnC
from Table1
) 
Group by COlumnC
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, it work very well, but is there any possibility to query  this in only one select statement? the query that i provide is just a part of the whole query and if i used three select statement, it will get error in oracle 11g :(

Comment: @Ricky - Can you post the full query so that we can check how it can be added

Answer (score -2):

Or you can simple use this query.

```
Select sum(columnB) as sum,columnC from table_name group by ColumnC;
```