# SQL sum non-distinct weights for distinct rows with category totals

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, distinct, cube

I want to cross-tabulate some weighted survey data in a context where an individual can contribute to more than one cell.  The challenge is to make sure that subtotals and grand totals are done without double-counting.

I can get the individual cell values but not the totals using methods similar to the solutions at [How do I SUM DISTINCT Rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464946/how-do-i-sum-distinct-rows) or [Sum Distinct By Other Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231853/sum-distinct-by-other-column) .  I'm trying to use the Oracle CUBE statement to get the totals in a nice way.

Here's a baby example.  Suppose we're counting people according to what pets they own and according to their hobbies.  The problem is that a person might have more than one pet, or more than one hobby.  We need to turn this set of unit records:

```
person_id, weight
1, 10
2, 10
3, 12

person_id, pet
1, "cat"
1, "dog"
2, "cat"
3, "cat"

person_id, hobby
1, "chess"
2, "chess"
2, "skydiving"
3, "skydiving"
```

into this pair of tables:

```
    Unweighted count

      | chess | skydiving | total
------+-------+-----------+--------
cat   |  2    |  2        | 3
------+-------+-----------+--------
dog   |  1    |  0        | 1
------+-------+-----------+--------
total |  2    |  2        | 3      


Weighted count

      | chess | skydiving | total
------+-------+-----------+--------
cat   |  20   |  22       | 32
------+-------+-----------+--------
dog   |  10   |  0        | 10
------+-------+-----------+--------
total |  20   |  22       | 32
```

Notice that the unweighted total for the "cat" row is 3, not 2+2=4, as person number 2 is counted in two different places.  Only three distinct people contribute to this row.  Similarly for other totals.

Notice that the weighted total for "cat, chess" is 20=10+10, as two different people each contribute weight 10 to this cell.

Notice that the grand total for the weighted table is 32.  This comes from people 1 and 2 contributing 10 each, and person 3 contributing 12.  The grand total is not just the sum of all the individual cells!

For the unweighted counts, I can get all the cell counts and totals by:

```
CREATE TABLE weights(person_id INTEGER, weight INTEGER);
INSERT INTO weights(person_id,weight) VALUES (1,10);
INSERT INTO weights(person_id,weight) VALUES (2,10);
INSERT INTO weights(person_id,weight) VALUES (3,12);

CREATE TABLE pets(person_id INTEGER, pet VARCHAR(3));
INSERT INTO pets(person_id,pet) VALUES (1,'cat');
INSERT INTO pets(person_id,pet) VALUES (1,'dog');
INSERT INTO pets(person_id,pet) VALUES (2,'cat');
INSERT INTO pets(person_id,pet) VALUES (3,'cat');

CREATE TABLE hobbies(person_id INTEGER, hobby VARCHAR(9));
INSERT INTO hobbies(person_id,hobby) VALUES (1,'chess');
INSERT INTO hobbies(person_id,hobby) VALUES (2,'chess');
INSERT INTO hobbies(person_id,hobby) VALUES (2,'skydiving');
INSERT INTO hobbies(person_id,hobby) VALUES (3,'skydiving');

SELECT pet, hobby, COUNT(DISTINCT weights.person_id)
FROM weights JOIN pets on weights.person_id=pets.person_ID
JOIN hobbies on weights.person_id=hobbies.person_id
GROUP BY CUBE(pet, hobby);
```

The combination of `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` and `CUBE` gives the correct totals.

For weighted counts, if I try the same idea:

```
SELECT pet, hobby, SUM(DISTINCT weight)
FROM weights JOIN pets on weights.person_id=pets.person_ID
JOIN hobbies on weights.person_id=hobbies.person_id
GROUP BY CUBE(pet, hobby);
```

the "cat, chess" cell comes to 10 not 20, because people 1 and 2 both have the same weight.  Removing the "distinct" key word means that the individual cell counts are correct but the totals are wrong (it produces a grand total of 52 where it should be 32, because persons 1 and 2 are double-counted in the total).

Any suggestions?

Comment: what if you remove the distinct within sum?

Comment: You mean SUM(weight)?  Then the "cat, chess" cell is correct, but the grand total is 52 where it should be 32, because persons 1 and 2 get counted twice each in the grand total.

Comment: but sum(distinct weight) is giving total 22 not 32.

Comment: Exactly.  The correct answer is 32, as person 1 and person 2 contribute 10 each and person 3 contributes 12.  SUM(distinct weight) gives the wrong answer, because it counts only 10 for people 1 and 2 together.  SUM(weight) gives a different wrong answer, because it counts people multiple times.  What I'm looking for is a reasonably simple way to get the number 32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a nested query, where the inner query specifies a mapping from rows to table cells (i.e. which records are in scope for each table cell), and the outer query specifies the summary function(s) to be applied:

```
SELECT pet, hobby, COUNT(1), SUM(weight) FROM
(SELECT pet, hobby, weights.person_ID, weight
FROM weights JOIN pets on weights.person_id=pets.person_ID
JOIN hobbies on weights.person_id=hobbies.person_id
GROUP BY CUBE(pet, hobby), weights.person_ID, weight)
GROUP BY pet, hobby;
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml7TQ.png)

Aside:  You can also write the inner query without using the CUBE operator, but it's a lot messier:

```
WITH
    pet_cube_map as (SELECT DISTINCT pet, NULL as pet_cubed FROM pets UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT pet, pet as pet_cubed FROM pets),
    hobby_cube_map as (SELECT DISTINCT hobby, NULL as hobby_cubed FROM hobbies UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT hobby, hobby as hobby_cubed FROM hobbies)
SELECT DISTINCT pet_cubed as pet, hobby_cubed as hobby, weights.person_ID, weight
FROM weights
    JOIN pets on weights.person_ID=pets.person_ID
    JOIN pet_cube_map on pets.pet=pet_cube_map.pet
    JOIN hobbies on weights.person_ID=hobbies.person_ID
    JOIN hobby_cube_map on hobbies.hobby=hobby_cube_map.hobby
;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, below gives the correct result but it is most simplified one

```
SELECT pet, hobby, SUM(weight)
FROM weights JOIN pets on weights.person_id=pets.person_ID
JOIN hobbies on weights.person_id=hobbies.person_id
GROUP BY pet, hobby
UNION
SELECT pet, NULL, SUM(weight)
FROM weights JOIN pets on weights.person_id=pets.person_ID
GROUP BY pet
UNION
SELECT NULL, hobby, SUM(weight)
FROM weights JOIN hobbies on weights.person_id=hobbies.person_id
GROUP BY hobby
UNION
SELECT SUM(weight)
FROM weights
```

still working on single select

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed give the correct totals.  The problem is that it's not easily scalable.  If I'm classifying along three dimensions (pet, hobby and another), then I need to manually generate all eight sets of cell counts, subtotals and totals.  For four dimensions, I'll have 16 SELECTs.  And so on.  The "baby example" I've given is just for proof of concept: I want to apply this in some more complicated scenarios.  If it can be done with a single SELECT plus a CUBE, then life is quite a lot easier!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do some math like this:

```
;WITH t AS (
    SELECT 
        p.pet,
        SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN h.hobby = 'chess' THEN POWER(2,h.person_id) ELSE 0 END) chess,
        SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN h.hobby = 'skydiving' THEN POWER(2,h.person_id) ELSE 0 END) skydiving,
        SUM(DISTINCT POWER(2,h.person_id)) total
    FROM 
        hobbies h
        LEFT JOIN
        pets p ON h.person_id = p.person_id
    GROUP BY
        p.pet
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        'total',
        SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN h.hobby = 'chess' THEN POWER(2,h.person_id) ELSE 0 END),
        SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN h.hobby = 'skydiving' THEN POWER(2,h.person_id) ELSE 0 END),
        SUM(DISTINCT POWER(2,h.person_id))
    FROM 
        hobbies h
), w(person_id, weight) as (
    SELECT POWER(2,person_id), weight
    FROM weights
), cte(person_id, weight) AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM w
    UNION ALL
    SELECT w1.person_id + w2.person_id, w1.weight + w2.weight
    FROM cte w1 JOIN w w2 ON w2.person_id > w1.person_id
)
SELECT 
    pet,
    COALESCE((SELECT cte.weight FROM cte WHERE cte.person_id = t.chess), 0) AS chess,
    COALESCE((SELECT cte.weight FROM cte WHERE cte.person_id = t.skydiving), 0) AS skydiving,
    COALESCE((SELECT cte.weight FROM cte WHERE cte.person_id = t.total), 0) AS total
FROM t;
```

Not cubed, static way and a bit dirty. But I just test it in SQL Server ;).

---

This can be a cubed version (Not tested):

```
;With t as (
SELECT  h.hobby, p.pet, POWER(2,h.person_id) weight
FROM    hobbies h 
JOIN    pets p
ON      h.person_id = p.person_id
JOIN    weights w
ON      h.person_id = w.person_id
), w(person_id, weight) as (
    SELECT POWER(2,person_id), weight
    FROM weights
), cte(person_id, weight) AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM w
    UNION ALL
    SELECT w1.person_id + w2.person_id, w1.weight + w2.weight
    FROM cte w1 JOIN w w2 ON w2.person_id > w1.person_id
), c as (
SELECT  
    hobby, pet, SUM(DISTINCT weight) person_id
FROM    t
GROUP BY CUBE(hobby, pet)
)
SELECT c.hobby, c.pet, cte.weight
FROM c JOIN
    cte ON c.person_id = cte.person_id;
```